# How to use Chrome webview with phonegap

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, cordova

I have built a HTML5 application and there is a problem with the default android web view with my application, some functions are not working properly
so I need to get the web view from chrome to my application...
I tried many ways with the default webview in Android but its useless..

Comment: There is no way you can use chromewebview with cordova because cordova itself using its own webview..you cant override it..I m also facing same issue...

Comment: soo haveto give up in that case and thank you...